# Why is phase velocity not a vector and what is the conceptual meaning of "phase slowness"?

Tags: waves, geometric-optics

I was reading *Principles of Optics* by *Born* and *Wolf*; there they introduced the concept of *phase velocity* as follows:

> [...] If we denote $\mathbf q$ the unit vector in the direction of $\mathrm d\mathbf r,$ and we write $\mathrm d\mathbf r ~=~ \mathbf q~\mathrm ds,$ then $(29)$ gives $$\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf s}{\mathrm dt} ~=~ \frac{\omega}{\mathbf q\cdot\textrm{grad} ~g}\,.\tag{30}$$ This expression will be numerically smallest when $\mathbf q$ is the normal to the co-phasal surface i.e. when $\mathbf q~=~ \textrm{grad}~g/|\textrm{grad}~g|,$ the value then being $$v
> ^{(p)}(\mathbf r)~=~ \frac\omega{|\textrm{grad}~g|}\,.\tag{31}$$  $v
> ^{(p)}(\mathbf r)$ is called the *phase velocity* and is the speed with which each of the co-phasal surfaces advances.
>
> [...] It must be noted that $\mathrm ds/\mathrm dt$ given by $(30)$ is not the resolute of the phase velocity in the $\mathbf q$-direction, i.e. the **phase velocity doesn't behave as a vector**. On the other hand its reciprocal, i.e. the quantity $$\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm ds}~=~ \frac{\mathbf q\cdot\textrm{grad} ~g}{\omega}\tag{32}$$ is seen to be the component of the vector ${\textrm{grad} ~g}/{\omega}$ in the $\mathbf q$ direction. The vector ${\textrm{grad} ~g}/{\omega}$ is sometimes called *phase slowness*.

I'm having some queries corresponding to the above para.

$\bullet$ Why is the phase velocity not a vector? Does that mean it has no direction? Does not it rotate like a vector? Why is it *velocity* then?

$\bullet$ The authors introduced *phase slowness* for the reciprocal of phase velocity. It is evident from $(32)$ that it is a component of a vector. However, what is the motivation of calling it *phase slowness*? Why did the author term it so?

Comment: Is my answer below acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the argument is quite involved and not clear mathematically. I try to reformulate it with a more familiar notations.

A scalar wave is a function, with both spatial and temporal dependency, $\Psi(\phi(x^i,t))$ where the dimensionless $\phi$ is called its *phase*. The hypersurfaces of the space-time where $\phi$ is a constant in space-time (e.g. $\theta$) is where the field $\Psi$ has the same value. For them the differential is zero (indexes repeated indicate sum):
\begin{equation}
\phi(x^i,t)=\theta \Rightarrow d\phi=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i}dx_i=0
\end{equation}
Then divide by $dt$ both sides and one can introduce a vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ that is the spatial point change over time:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i} \frac{dx_i}{dt}:=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^i} v^i = -\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
The lhs above is the projection of the velocity on the gradient to the 2D wavefront. The gradient is always orthogonal to the surface. Now divide by the size of the gradient. The projection of our velocity vector on the normal unit vector is called *phase velocity*:
\begin{equation}
v_p=\frac{\boldsymbol{\nabla}(\phi)} {|\boldsymbol{\nabla}(\phi)|}\cdot \boldsymbol{v}=-\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{\nabla}(\phi)|}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
This is the (scalar) velocity with which the spatial 2D surfaces propagate. Obviously one can define a phase velocity vector, but that must be parallel to the gradient of the phase 2D surface, to be coherent with our previous definition:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{v}_p:=\frac{\boldsymbol{\nabla}(\phi)} {|\boldsymbol{\nabla}(\phi)|}v_p
\end{equation}

The most fundamental wave has 2D planes as phase wavefronts in the 3D space:
\begin{equation}
\phi(x,t)=k_ix^i -\omega t +\varphi
\end{equation}
for which
\begin{equation}
v_{p}=-\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{\nabla}(\phi)|}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=\frac{\omega}{|\boldsymbol{k}|}\\
\\
\boldsymbol{v}_p=\frac{\omega}{|\boldsymbol{k}|}\hat{{\boldsymbol{k}}}
\end{equation}

So the components of $\boldsymbol{v}_p$ are **not** $v_{pi}=\omega/k_i$.

The parameters $\partial \phi/\partial t=\omega$ and $\partial \phi/\partial x^i=k_i$, not necessarily independent on each other, measure the variation of the phase by the time and space respectively. They have dimension of a [time]$^{-1}$ and [length]$^{-1}$ respectively.

This is first time for me to read about the phase slowness. I have never seen in other books.